# Subtract equations: Confusion about what is meant here

Tags: real-analysis, linear-pde

I am referring to
[this document](http://www.pdecomp.net/generalPapers/BacklundTransformation.pdf) on Backlund transformations.

In this paper, one has equations (50),
$$
\begin{align*}
(w_1+w_0)_x&=2\lambda_1+\frac{1}{2}(w_1-w_0)^2\\
(w_2+w_0)_x&=2\lambda_2+\frac{1}{2}(w_2-w_0)^2
\end{align*},
$$
and equations (51),
$$
\begin{align*}
(w_{12}+w_1)_x&=2\lambda_1+\frac{1}{2}(w_{12}-w_1)^2\\
(w_{21}+w_2)_x&=2\lambda_2+\frac{1}{2}(w_{21}-w_2)^2
\end{align*},
$$

Then it is said:

> subtract the difference of eqns (50) from the difference of eqns (51) to give
> $$
> 0=4(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)+\frac{1}{2}[(w_{12}-w_1)^2-(w_{21}-w_2)^2-(w_1-w_0)^2+(w_2-w_0)^2]
> $$

I do not understand what is meant.
What do I have to subtract from what?
I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A=B$

$C=D$

$E=F$

$G=H$

Subtract the difference of first two equations  from the difference of second two equations means

subtract $A-C=B-D$ from $E-G=F-H$. So you get $(E-G)-(A-C)=(F-H)-(B-D)$.